# PowerShell: defining multiple conditions in Where-Object

Tags: arrays, where-clause, powershell-5.0

I have a sample array and I try to create a rule which will filter our either of the 2 items that are present in the array.

Sample array:

```
$d_c_arr = @('idata', 'quanthouse', 'reuters', 'bloomberg', 'fidelity', 'nasdaq')
```

The items that I want to filter out are '`idata`' and '`quanthouse`'.

The filtering rule should adapt to the situations where either both '`idata`' and '`quanthouse`' exist or only one of them is present in an array.

My attempt to define the rule:

```
$d_c_arr | Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'idata' -or $_ -notlike 'quanthouse' }
```

My expected output would be:

```
reuters
bloomberg
fidelity
nasdaq
```

However, the actual output is:

```
idata
quanthouse
reuters
bloomberg
fidelity
nasdaq
```

How to properly define the rule which would filter either of the 2 selected items in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d_c_arr | sls -pattern 'idata|quanthouse' -notmatch
```

[[LIVE](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwEADvfcUeCmmhPqHQn8hqtiawZjW7oQj@PTUIpbeZw8wiH8oaiLnWq@/HHnOGJ7xuLno0dA9wa8FkQYpSs0zFjqLhwCLzQHlq8o6eONrWOKF6XN398jvuoKzQLWhHnOCc739n6JLYjDaGWr8)]

Your object are .net strings so can use select-string cmdlet.
select-string takes [regex](https://regex101.com/r/DRTZeW/1) as its pattern.